# I'm trying to make a search function for a multidimensional array in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, search, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to search a multidimensional array in java script but I can't get it to work. I want to input the first number from one of the 3 rows and get the entire row. Basically, I want the result to be a given row in the preheat array. If I input 20 I want the alert to give 20, 0.75, 26.9, 116, 5, 2, 1, "5x3".

The alert box gives me no numbers at all and the chrome javascript console gives no errors. I think the problem is in how I handle the result array.

Here is the html:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="arraycode.js">
</script>
</head>

<body>
<table>
<tr><td>Nominal Diameter DN (mm):</td>
<td><input id="DN" onchange="tablesearch();"></td>
</table>


</body>


</html>
```

Here is the javascript:

```
function tablesearch(){

var preheat= [[15, 0.5, 21.3, 98, 4, 2, 1, "4x4"],
            [20, 0.75, 26.9, 116, 5, 2, 1, "5x3"],
            [25, 1, 33.7, 137, 6, 2, 1, "6x6"]];
var DN=document.getElementById("DN").value;


var result= new Array();
for (var i=0; i<preheat.length; i= i+1){
    if (preheat[i][0]===DN){
        result=preheat[i];
        break;
        }
}
alert(result);

}
```

Comment: Define "it doesn't work", and state the output you want.

Comment: Why are you only testing the first member of the nested Arrays? Is that intentional? Also, you'll never get a match, because you're comparing strings to numbers using `===`.

Comment: Alright changing === to == fixed the problem thanks @CrazyTrain. I thought I was comparing just numbers not strings, I don't understand why that was the problem.

Comment: @user2606257: Values from  input elements are always strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the following line:

```
if (preheat[i][0]===DN){
```

The === operator checks that the type matches as well as the value. In this case, the value from the input is a string, while the value in the array is an integer, so no match. Use == instead and it will work.

Comment: Yup this fixed the problem, I just want to know hwy DN in my code is considered a string.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
for (var i=0; i<preheat.length; i++){
 for(var j=0;j<preheat[i].length;j++){
    if (preheat[i][j]===DN){
        result=preheat[i]; //Are you after the entire array here?
        break;
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: I want the result to be a given row in the preheat array. If I input 20 I want the alert to give 20, 0.75, 26.9, 116, 5, 2, 1, "5x3"